# Install Bash Kernel on Windows for using in Jupyter

Tags: windows, bash, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have installed python 3.6.3 on my windows via Anaconda. I am using Jupyter notebook and want to use bash kernel on it.
Tried this command :

```
pip install bash_kernel
python -m bash_kernel.install
```

The above command is throwing invalid syntax error.

Refering https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bash_kernel

any help on this?
Windows version is 8

Comment: I had a look at the kernel code and it looks like a wrapper to bash at the OS level.  Since you are on Windows, I  doubt that will work.  If you use Anaconda on Linux it does work (I just tried on Mint 18).

Comment: @Nic3500Is there any way to access terminal and bash commands in Jupyter from windows?

Comment: Bash on Windows?  ~yes~.  You can use Cygwin (beurk!) or run a virtual linux machine.  But as far as using bash inside Jupyter on Windows, I doubt it, but I do not have a definitive answer on that.  You can check that, unknown if it will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about

Comment: I would highly recommend the Windows-Bash shell, have a look: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use bash commands in Jupyter Notebook, even on Windows systems, as long as Jupyter is launched from a bash-compliant command line such as [Git Bash (MingW64)](https://gitforwindows.org/) or possibly [Ubuntu on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0).

I'm running windows 10 Pro with Python installed via Anaconda, and the following code works when I launch Jupyter via Git Bash, but does not when I launch from the Anaconda prompt.

```
>>> !ls
database.sqlite
Weather Data Clustering using k-Means.ipynb

>>>!pip show lxml | grep Version
Version: 4.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, this is what i did;

1. install Git/Git bash application on your windows. https://git-scm.com/download/win

Use the default installation options(continue to click on "Next" until you see "Install", click on "Install" to install the app)

2.Follow this link to setup conda in the Git Bash. https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/setting-up-conda-in-git-bash/534473

3. Close the Git bash and reopen, then type `jupyter notebook` and click `Enter`. This will lunch your Jupyter notebook from Git bash and you can now use bash commands in your Jupyter kernel.

NB: You will always need to activate conda anytime you want to use Jupyter from the Git bash. Type the command `conda activate` and hit `Enter` (You should see (base) pop up above your prompt) then type  `jupyter notebook` after that.